# jquery: get values of all children of a div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to get the values of all children element of a div.

```
<div class='parent'>
    <input type='text' value='1' class='child' />
    <input type='text' value='2' class='child' />
    <input type='text' value='3' class='child' />
    <input type='text' value='4' class='child' />
</div>
```

The child inputs are generated with php from db. Their number varies.

I am trying to get something like:

```
variable = (child1_value + child2_value + child3_value + child4_value + ... + "childX_value");
```

how can I make this work for whatever number of children?

Answer (score 6):

You can use each...

```
var total = 0;

$(".child").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Or similar

Comment: this will also add any inputs with class .child that are outside the .parent div, so I would be more specific in my selector `$(".parent .child").each...` but otherwise this is the best one :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = 0;
$('.parent input').each(function() {
  value += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = [];
    $('.child').each(function(){
       array.push($(this).val()); // store in an array for reuse
    });
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total += parseInt(array[i]); // sum up values in the array
    }
    alert(total);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add these values.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5PHTV/1/)**

```
sum = 0;
$('.parent :input').each(function(){     
      sum+= parseFloat($(this).val());
})
alert(sum);
```

Comment: OK, can you explain the use of `:input` as an pseudo class in your selector? This syntax is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 0;
$("input").each(function(index,value){ 
  result += parseFloat($(this).val());
});

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JmsAb/1/
```